# Bluefish editor highlights and unhighlights the text as I type - a kind of blinking effect

Tags: bluefish

I've just installed `Bluefish` editor. The problem I face, is that when I print something, it starts blinking and as a result some letters are not printed and I have to type them again. By blinking I mean that it highlights the current folder and current file and then removes this highlight. I do not know how to fix it. The way I run bluefish is just:

```
$ bluefish myfile.js
```

Here is a screen shot

[image]

This `services` folder and `authentication.js` file get and lose focus almost every third letter I type.

Comment: are you sure that your thumb isn't hovering very close to the touch pad when you type? In the touchpad settings on most systems, you can set to disable touch pad while typing.

Comment: I'm not using any touch pad. I have a standard keyboard. In a second I will post a screen of the situation.

Comment: I mean, my keyboard does not have any touch pad.

Comment: yes, I was thinking you were on a laptop. touchpad interference is common until one gets used to reorienting hand placement to avoid it.

Comment: By the way, if file extension is not supported by Bluefish, then it is all ok. So it looks as some Bluefish bug or feature

Comment: For example, if in my PHP file, I start its contents with `<php` or just some rubbish, then I face to blinking, when however I change it to `<?php`, I get into this trouble. Unfortunatelly, in JavaScript files I see no workaround

Comment: can you turn off text highlighting? My guess, it is rehighlighting the text while you type. This taking a second and losing a typed charactor.

Comment: Yeah, I removed it and its ok now. Though, the code is not so well readable now. But it is better then to have this blinking.

Comment: @Jacobian That makes for an answer, do you mind adding it as one below?

Comment: I don't think, that it is an answer, it is a hack, that solves the issue, but makes your work in the editor very inconvenient.